# asp.net extract string from json

Tags: asp.net

Hi how can I parse this json data into a list of strings

```
{'Roles':['Role1','Role2','Role3','Role4']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is always going to be in that format then the following should work:

`class RoleList
{
  public List<String> Roles { get;set; }
}`

and then:
`(new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize< RoleList >( strInput )` will get you back a RoleList instance.

If you do not know in advance the structure of the object, you will have to use:
`(new JavaScriptSerializer()).DeserializeObject( strInput )` which will get you back an object that you can inspect using reflexion.

The JavaScriptSerializer is in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Comment: Thanks
will the first string ie Roles also e included in the list?